# Inserting multiple records in mySQL with NodeJS preventing injection and getting each record's ID

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, ajax

I have an ajax request that adds one or multiple records to a table (the following code is server side):

```
app.post('/saveLesson',function(req, res) {

    let sections = JSON.parse(req.body.sections);

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO sections (title, content, duration) VALUES ';

    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

        if (i == sections.length-1) {
            sql += '("' + sections[i].title + '","' + sections[i].content + '","' + sections[i].duration + '");';
        } else {
            sql += '("' + sections[i].title + '","' + sections[i].content + '","' + sections[i].duration + '"),';
        }
    }
    connection.query(sql, 
        function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw error;
    });

});
```

I want to prevent SQL injection, but I'm not sure how to do it for multiple records.

Generally I know that I would have to build my sql statement as follows:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM bank_accounts WHERE dob = ? AND bank_account = ?",
    [
     req.body.dob,
     req.body.account_number
    ],
    function(error, results) { 

    }
);
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this with multiple records (not knowing how many they are). Is the .query parameter just a regular array?

Also, I need to store somewhere the created IDs and send them back to the client page. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

***************************** UPDATE *****************************

Although someone posted a solution, I thought this might be useful. With the following code you can add multiple records preventing SQL injections.

```
app.post('/saveLesson',function(req, res) {

    let sections = JSON.parse(req.body.sections);

    console.log(sections);

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO sections (title, duration, content) VALUES ';

    // I make a new array to pass the list of values to the query
    let sectionsParamList = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

        if (i == sections.length-1) {
            sql += '(?,?,?);';
        } else {
            sql += '(?,?,?),';
        }

        sectionsParamList.push(sections[i].title);
        sectionsParamList.push(sections[i].duration);
        sectionsParamList.push(sections[i].content);
    }

    connection.query(sql, sectionsParamList,
        function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw error;
    });

});
```

Comment: `Also I need to store somewhere the created IDs and send them back to the client page.` Instead of using autoincrement primary keys you could generate them yourself, i.e. http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/

Comment: Interesting link, thank you. On the client side I also have IDs for the records I will insert (an incremental number + Math.random() - those are unique only in the client page, not on the DB). Would it be advisable to add the records with this ID along with other information and then retrieve the unique ID created by the database using the "dummy" IDs? I suppose I would end up with a useless field unless I recycle it for some other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way MySQL works, when you perform a multi-row `INSERT` operation like the one you propose, you only get back the automatically generated unique `id` of the last row inserted. It shows up in your `result` object as `result.insertId`. Don't try to guess the `id` values of the other rows, by subtraction for example, because there's no guarantee of that.

The fact that you need that `id` for every row you insert means you should not use a multi-row insert, but rather a sequence of single row inserts.  That neatly solves your SQL injection issue too.

But you will have to figure out how to do a sequence of `INSERT` operations. You may want to do it with an async  / await / promise setup. Something like this, **not debugged**.

```
/* do one insert with a Promise so you can await it */
function doInsert (section, connection) {
   const values = [section.title, section.content, section.duration];
   return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
      const sql = "INSERT INTO sections (title, content, duration) VALUES (?,?,?);"
      connection.query (sql, values, function ( error, result ) {
         if (error) reject (error)
         resolve (result.insertId)
      } )
   } )
}

/* do all the inserts, awaiting each one */
async function doInserts (sections, connection) {
  let ids = []
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
     const id = await doInsert (sections[i], connection) 
     ids.push(id) 
  }
  return ids
}
```

```
/* handle your post */
app.post('/saveLesson',function(req, res) {
  let sections = JSON.parse(req.body.sections)
  /* get the result back from an async function with .then / .catch */
  doInserts (sections, connection)
  .then (function (resultIds) {
     /* respond with the id values in a JSON object */
     res.status(200).json(resultIds)
  } )
  .catch ( function (error) {
     /* respond with an error */
     res.status(500).json(error)
  } )
} )
```

These async / await and Promise language constructions are really worth your trouble to learn, if you don't already know them.

Comment: I admit I don't know much about async / await and Promise. I definitely need to learn how to use them. Thank you for your post.